# Ubuntu Not Recognizing WiFi Chip Intel AC 9260

Tags: networking

I made a fresh install on new laptop with Ubuntu (several distros) 19.10 and the wifi chip is not recognized (there is no wifi setting). I tried installing 18.04 LTS but that didn't help. I tired many of the commands (reinstalling headers, restarting network manager, using bootcamp) but none of them worked? Kind of losing hope at this point, does anyone have anymore suggestions?

Edit 1:

```
73:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2526] (rev 29)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0014]
Kernel modules: iwlwifi, wl
74:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:a808]
```

Everything for rfkill list is no (no soft or hard blocks)

Comment: Can you provide the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -i network -A 3` and `rfkill list` ?

Comment: 73:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2526] (rev 29)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0014]
Kernel modules: iwlwifi, wl
74:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device [144d:a808]

Everything for rfkill list is no (no soft or hard blocks)

Comment: Sorry, I forget to tell you to add it directly in your question, it will be easy for people to read it, can you add it ?

Comment: Sure, just did.

Answer (score 1):

It seems I also encounter this wifi issue on my Ubuntu 18.04 laptop.

Tried to solve it by myself and it could be fixed by following steps.
You may refer it to see whether it can solve the problem on your side.

1. remove the problematic firmware manually

   ```
   $ sudo mv /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode $HOME
   ```
2. reload the `iwlwifi`

   ```
   $ sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi; sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
   ```

Then wifi works well.

Comment: There's a glaring error here: `sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi; sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi` should be `sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi; sudo modprobe iwlwifi`